# Loading and dumping multiple yaml files with ruamel.yaml (python)

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

Using python 2 (atm) and ruamel.yaml 0.13.14 (RedHat EPEL)

I'm currently writing some code to load yaml definitions, but they are split up in multiple files. The user-editable part contains eg.

```
users:
  xxxx1:
    timestamp: '2018-10-22 11:38:28.541810'
    << : *userdefaults
  xxxx2:
    << : *userdefaults
    timestamp: '2018-10-22 11:38:28.541810'
```

the defaults are stored in another file, which is not editable:

```
userdefaults: &userdefaults
    # Default values for user settings
    fileCountQuota: 1000
    diskSizeQuota: "300g"
```

I can process these together by loading both and concatinating the strings, and then running them through `merged_data = list(yaml.load_all("{}\n{}".format(defaults_data, user_data), Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader))` which correctly resolves everything. (when not using RoundTripLoader I get errors that the references cannot be resolved, which is normal)

Now, I want to do some updates via python code (eg. update the timestamp), and for that I need to just write back the user part. And that's where things get hairy. I sofar haven't found a way to just write that yaml document, not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, unless there are multiple documents in your defaults file, you 
don't have to use `load_all`, as you don't concatenate two documents into a
multiple-document stream. If you had by using a format string with a document-end
marker (`"{}\n...\n{}"`) or with a directives-end marker (`"{}\n---\n{}"`)
your aliases would not carry over from one document to another, as per the 
YAML specification:

> It is an error for an alias node to use an anchor that does not
>     previously occur in the document.

The anchor has to be in the document, not just in the stream (which can consist of multiple
documents).

---

I tried some hocus pocus, pre-populating the already represented dictionary 
of anchored nodes:

```
import sys
import datetime
from ruamel import yaml

def load():
    with open('defaults.yaml') as fp:
        defaults_data = fp.read()
    with open('user.yaml') as fp:
        user_data = fp.read()
    merged_data = yaml.load("{}\n{}".format(defaults_data, user_data), 
                            Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)
    return merged_data

class MyRTDGen(object):
    class MyRTD(yaml.RoundTripDumper):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
            pps = kw.pop('pre_populate', None)
            yaml.RoundTripDumper.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
            if pps is not None:
                for pp in pps:
                    try:
                        anchor = pp.yaml_anchor()
                    except AttributeError:
                        anchor = None
                    node = yaml.nodes.MappingNode(
                        u'tag:yaml.org,2002:map', [], flow_style=None, anchor=anchor)
                    self.represented_objects[id(pp)] = node

    def __init__(self, pre_populate=None):
        assert isinstance(pre_populate, list)
        self._pre_populate = pre_populate 

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        kw1 = kw.copy()
        kw1['pre_populate'] = self._pre_populate
        myrtd = self.MyRTD(*args, **kw1)
        return myrtd


def update(md, file_name):
    ud = md.pop('userdefaults')
    MyRTD = MyRTDGen([ud])
    yaml.dump(md, sys.stdout, Dumper=MyRTD)
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
        yaml.dump(md, fp, Dumper=MyRTD)

md = load()
md['users']['xxxx2']['timestamp'] = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
update(md, 'user.yaml')
```

Since the PyYAML based API requires a class instead of an object, you need to 
use a class generator, that actually adds the data elements to pre-populate on
the fly from withing `yaml.load()`.

But this doesn't work, as a node only gets written out with an anchor once it is
determined that the anchor is used (i.e. there is a second reference). So actually the
first merge key gets written out as an anchor. And although I am quite familiar
with the code base, I could not get this to work properly in a reasonable amount of time.

So instead, I would just rely on the fact that there is only one key that matches
the first key of `users.yaml` at the root level of the dump of the combined updated
file and strip anything before that.

```
import sys
import datetime
from ruamel import yaml

with open('defaults.yaml') as fp:
    defaults_data = fp.read()
with open('user.yaml') as fp:
    user_data = fp.read()
merged_data = yaml.load("{}\n{}".format(defaults_data, user_data), 
                        Loader=yaml.RoundTripLoader)

# find the key
for line in user_data.splitlines():
    line = line.split('# ')[0].rstrip()  # end of line comment, not checking for strings
    if line and line[-1] == ':' and line[0] != ' ':
        split_key = line
        break

merged_data['users']['xxxx2']['timestamp'] = str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())

buf = yaml.compat.StringIO()
yaml.dump(merged_data, buf, Dumper=yaml.RoundTripDumper)
document = split_key + buf.getvalue().split('\n' + split_key)[1]
sys.stdout.write(document)
```

which gives:

```
users:
  xxxx1:
    <<: *userdefaults
    timestamp: '2018-10-22 11:38:28.541810'
  xxxx2:
    <<: *userdefaults
    timestamp: '2018-10-23 09:59:13.829978'
```

---

I had to make a virtualenv to make sure I could run the above with `ruamel.yaml==0.13.14`.
That version is from the time I was still young (I won't claim to have been innocent).
There have been over 85 releases of the library since then.

I can understand that you might not be able to run anything but
Python2 at the moment and cannot compile/use a newer version. But what
you really should do is install `virtualenv` (can be done using EPEL, but also without
further "polluting" your system installation), make a virtualenv for the
code you are developping and install the latest version of `ruamel.yaml` (and
your other libraries) in there. You can also do that if you need
to distribute your software to other systems, just install virtualenv there as well.

I have all my utilties under `/opt/util`, and managed
[`virtualenvutils`](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenvutils/) a
wrapper around virtualenv.

Answer (score 0):

For writing the user part, you will have to manually split the output of `yaml.dump()` multifile output and write the appropriate part back to users yaml file.

```
import datetime
import StringIO

import ruamel.yaml

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='rt')
data = None

with open('defaults.yaml', 'r') as defaults:
    with open('users.yaml', 'r') as users:
        raw = "{}\n{}".format(''.join(defaults.readlines()), ''.join(users.readlines()))
        data = list(yaml.load_all(raw))

data[0]['users']['xxxx1']['timestamp'] = datetime.datetime.now().isoformat()

with open('users.yaml', 'w') as outfile:
    sio = StringIO.StringIO()
    yaml.dump(data[0], sio)
    out = sio.getvalue()
    outfile.write(out.split('\n\n')[1]) # write the second part here as this is the contents of users.yaml
```

Comment: Although the approach is OK, this won't work with 0.13.14 as the OP indicates is being used. There is also no need to use `load_all`, convert to a list and then only use the first element unless there are multiple documents in the `defaults.yaml` file (and then updating `data[0]` would not work).