# Manually adding items using ruamel CommentedMap()

Tags: python-2.7, ruamel.yaml

As a followup to my previous [[Loading and dumping multiple yaml files with ruamel.yaml (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52943337/loading-and-dumping-multiple-yaml-files-with-ruamel-yaml-python](ruamel.yaml) question), I'm trying now to insert items into the tree. I'm using `CommentedMaps()`, so that I can also insert my own anchors/references in the tree.

Relevant parts of the code:
In case no users: tree is present yet, I create this:

```
if 'users' not in merged_yaml:
    merged_yaml['users'] = [ CommentedMap() ]
    merged_yaml['users'][0].yaml_set_anchor('users')
```

and then adding them like

```
merged_yaml['users'][0][user_name] = CommentedMap({'timestamp': current_date}, relax=True)
merged_yaml['users'][0][user_name].add_yaml_merge([(0, userdefaults)])
```

So, while this works, I get an inconsistent result, as you can see (output of 
`pprint(merged_yaml['users'])` - manually indented). The problem lies in user3 being merged inside the map of user2.

```
[ordereddict([
    ('user1', ordereddict([
        ('timestamp', '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'), 
        ('files', 1000), 
        ('quota', 200)
    ])), 
    ('user2', ordereddict([
        ('timestamp', '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'), 
        ('files', 1000), 
        ('quota', 200)
     ])), 
     ('user3', ordereddict([
         ('timestamp', '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'), 
         ('files', 1000), 
         ('quota', 200)
     ]))
    ])
]
```

I've been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong, but I can't spot it.

```
users:
-   user1:
        <<: *userdefaults
        timestamp: '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'
    user2:
        <<: *userdefaults
        timestamp: '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'
    user3:
        <<: *userdefaults
        timestamp: '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'
```

What I was expecting is:

```
[ordereddict([
    ('user1', ordereddict([
    ....
    ]))
]),
ordereddict([
    ('user2', ordereddict([
    ....
    ]))
])
]

users:
-   user1:
        <<: *userdefaults
        timestamp: '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'
-    user2:
        <<: *userdefaults
        timestamp: '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'
-    user3:
        <<: *userdefaults
        timestamp: '2018-10-25 11:16:42.13241
```

Comment: Please try to provide a minimal working example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so other can copy/paste your code and try to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You manually wrapped "user1" by only leaving the `)` after the quota line.
If you do the same for the quota line for "user2", and also put the quota for "user3" on a newline you'll see that the indentation
throws you off-balance in interpreting the output.

```
[ordereddict([
    ('user1', ordereddict([
        ('timestamp', '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'), 
        ('files', 1000), 
        ('quota', 200)
    ])), 
#     ^ closing for tuple
#    ^ closing for ordereddict
#   ^ closing for list of ordereddict tuples
    ('user2', ordereddict([
        ('timestamp', '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'), 
        ('files', 1000), 
        ('quota', 200)
    ])), 
        ('user3', ordereddict([
            ('timestamp', '2018-10-25 11:16:42.132415'), 
            ('files', 1000), 
            ('quota', 200)
        ]))
#   ^^^^ extra indent in 5 preceding lines
    ])
]
```

---

Based on the expected output you want a single mapping per sequence element, and your sequence having multiple elements. For that, in Python, you need to append your `CommentedMap` to the list:

```
merged_yaml['users'] = x = []
for user in users:
   cm = CommentedMap()
   cm[user] = CommentedMap({'timestamp': current_date}, relax=True)
   cm.add_yaml_merge([(0, userdefaults)])    
   x.append(cm)
```

Comment: Updated my OP and added what I was expecting to get.

Comment: Updated my answer, you need to `.append()` to the list you create, not assign more key-values to the CommentedMap at the top of the list. The confusion probably comes from CommentedMaps, being a sorted of ordereddict, prettyprinting as lists of tuples. A good way to test is  to load what you expect, then prettyprint the loaded datastructure.

Comment: Indeed, that was what was throwing me off. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: One last thing - how can i add an anchor to the ['users'] subtree? Doesn't seem to stick/work.

Comment: You currently only get an anchor when the collection item is used somewhere else  (i.e. referenced). If you don't force an alias you also don't get an anchor.

Comment: Ok. Would be nice as a feature  ;)

Comment: @devilkin Yes, that is already in the bug/feature request database.

Comment: @devilkin While looking at what it would take to dump anchors for unreferenced objects, I found, there is an option for `yaml_set_anchor()`: `always_dump=True`. I added that back in 2015 %-)

Comment: I've been testing this, yet, I can't get this to work. In the last example, I want to apply the anchor on 'users', but since that is a list (not a CommentedMap), I can't apply an anchor on it.

Comment: `users` is a scalar string, are you sure you are not confusing that with the value for the key `users`, because that is sequence/list. The list-like structure you can attach anchors & comments on is `CommentedSeq`. What you should do is load the YAML that you want (from file or in-program string) and then dump it to make sure everything you need is preserved. If so, inspect the data structure you get from loading. From that you can deduce how to construct things from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for that `CommentedSeq` ;) I came across it before but it was unclear what it really was. Solved my issues with this.